# Building a 'case' of beer bottles in WooCommerce mini-cart.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

Really trying to nail an issue I can't quite complete. I've raised a query already but reckon I was likely unclear so hopefully a little clearer here.

I have amended the mini-cart to display a different image for every item added to the cart. This is to simulate the adding of bottles to a 'case'. See image to show in action, and here is the code which makes it work.

```
<?php 
if(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0){
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/…/empty-case.png" alt="icon" />';
} elseif (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 1){
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/…/uploads/2017/06/case-with-1-bottle.png" alt="icon" />';
elseif (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 2){
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/…/uploa…/2017/06/case-with-2-bottles.png" alt="icon" />';
```

This continues until about 60 bottles or so, and works fine.

The problem is, it's based on cart total, and there are other items in the shop that I **don't** want to include within this. **I only want this for the 'single bottles' product category**, but **not** for 't-shirts' *(for example)*.

Ideally, I'd love to just add something to exclude the other categories but I'm unsure what needs to be done.

Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: Mini cart bottle case]

Comment: Can you provide more context? What have you tried so far? How does `get_cart_contents_count()` work exactly and what types of objects are in the cart?

I bet, if you answer the above questions you can answer this question on your own. Fundamentally, your code is necessarily wrong. You want this section to only change based on the count of single bottles in the cart, but you are using the total count.

Comment: Also note that, by using a variable, you should be able to do away with all that counting/multiple if statements.  if ($this_is_beer) $img = "something_".$beer_count."_else.png";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a calculation for your product category "single bottles", this way:

```
<?php
    // Set HERE your product category
    $category = 'single bottles';

    $beer_count = 0;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->get_id() ) ){
            $beer_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    if ( $beer_count == 0 ) {
        echo '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/…/empty-case.png" alt="icon" />';
    } elseif ( $beer_count == 1 ) {
        echo '<img src="http://example.com/…/uploads/2017/06/case-with-1-bottle.png" alt="icon" />';
    } elseif ( $beer_count == 2 ) {
        echo '<img src="http://example.com/…/uploa…/2017/06/case-with-2-bottles.png" alt="icon" />';
    }
```

This should work…

Comment: You sir, are a champion. Thank you very, very much, it's hugely appreciated. I most certainly you a beer!

Comment: @SBNewland Just used to woocommerce a bit :) Thanks